# Logon screen doesn't display Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS

Tags: boot, nvidia, 22.04

For some time I have been having the previously intermittent but now constant problem that, when I boot up my system Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS , where the logon screen is supposed to be displayed, the screen is a uniform grey. I can logon blind, but then nothing displays except my wallpaper - no menus, no icons, nothing. Pressing Ctrl-Alt-T doesn't being up a terminal. Previously I could take some actions like this, albeit at a much reduced screen resolution. My current workaround is to boot up in safe mode instead, then immediately resume (Repair Broken Packages hasn't found anything the last couple of times that I've tried it). I get a blinking cursor at the top left of an otherwise blank screen for about 25 seconds, then can log in as normal. Whenever I have been able to check installed graphics drivers, they have been reported as fine. e.g.
sudo ubuntu-drivers install
[sudo] password for xxxx:
All the available drivers are already installed.
The graphics card is an NVIDIA GP108 [GeForce GT 1030] with the NVIDIA driver metapackage nvidia-driver-535 (the latest one) installed.